# Failed to fetch error in onSubmit function button

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, function, fetch

I am following the simple records list tutorial for MongoDB's for MERN stack [here](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial). I followed all the instructions and fixed up my connection and it is working. However when I test out the app and try to create a new record by clicking `Create Person`, nothing happens. Also, when I refresh the create page the alert box pops up with the error saying failed to fetch.

Now, when I click on create person again after refreshing, no alert box pops up even after refreshing again. The button doesn't navigate back to the homepage which is what I need it to do.

```
// /client/src/components/create.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
export default function Create() {
 const [form, setForm] = useState({
   name: "",
   position: "",
   level: "",
 });
 const navigate = useNavigate();
  // These methods will update the state properties.
 function updateForm(value) {
   return setForm((prev) => {
     return { ...prev, ...value };
   });
 }
  // This function will handle the submission.
 async function onSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    // When a post request is sent to the create url, we'll add a new record to the database.
   const newPerson = { ...form };
    await fetch("http://localhost:5000/record/add", {
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(newPerson),
   })
   .catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
     return;
   });
    setForm({ name: "", position: "", level: "" });
   navigate("/");
 }
  // This following section will display the form that takes the input from the user.
 return (
   <div>
     <h3>Create New Record</h3>
     <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
       <div className="form-group">
         <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
         <input
           type="text"
           className="form-control"
           id="name"
           value={form.name}
           onChange={(e) => updateForm({ name: e.target.value })}
         />
       </div>
       <div className="form-group">
         <label htmlFor="position">Position</label>
         <input
           type="text"
           className="form-control"
           id="position"
           value={form.position}
           onChange={(e) => updateForm({ position: e.target.value })}
         />
       </div>
       <div className="form-group">
         <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
           <input
             className="form-check-input"
             type="radio"
             name="positionOptions"
             id="positionIntern"
             value="Intern"
             checked={form.level === "Intern"}
             onChange={(e) => updateForm({ level: e.target.value })}
           />
           <label htmlFor="positionIntern" className="form-check-label">Intern</label>
         </div>
         <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
           <input
             className="form-check-input"
             type="radio"
             name="positionOptions"
             id="positionJunior"
             value="Junior"
             checked={form.level === "Junior"}
             onChange={(e) => updateForm({ level: e.target.value })}
           />
           <label htmlFor="positionJunior" className="form-check-label">Junior</label>
         </div>
         <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
           <input
             className="form-check-input"
             type="radio"
             name="positionOptions"
             id="positionSenior"
             value="Senior"
             checked={form.level === "Senior"}
             onChange={(e) => updateForm({ level: e.target.value })}
           />
           <label htmlFor="positionSenior" className="form-check-label">Senior</label>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className="form-group">
         <input
           type="submit"
           value="Create person"
           className="btn btn-primary"
         />
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
 );
}
```

I am also wondering why the records don't show up in the records list.

```
// /client/src/components/recordList.js

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const Record = (props) => (
 <tr>
   <td>{props.record.name}</td>
   <td>{props.record.position}</td>
   <td>{props.record.level}</td>
   <td>
     <Link className="btn btn-link" to={`/edit/${props.record._id}`}>Edit</Link> |
     <button className="btn btn-link"
       onClick={() => {
         props.deleteRecord(props.record._id);
       }}
     >
       Delete
     </button>
   </td>
 </tr>
);
export default function RecordList() {
 const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);
  // This method fetches the records from the database.
 useEffect(() => {
   async function getRecords() {
     const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/record/`);
      if (!response.ok) {
       const message = `An error occurred: ${response.statusText}`;
       window.alert(message);
       return;
     }
      const records = await response.json();
     setRecords(records);
   }
    getRecords();
    return;
 }, [records.length]);
  // This method will delete a record
 async function deleteRecord(id) {
   await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/${id}`, {
     method: "DELETE"
   });
    const newRecords = records.filter((el) => el._id !== id);
   setRecords(newRecords);
 }
  // This method will map out the records on the table
 function recordList() {
   return records.map((record) => {
     return (
       <Record
         record={record}
         deleteRecord={() => deleteRecord(record._id)}
         key={record._id}
       />
     );
   });
 }
  // This following section will display the table with the records of individuals.
 return (
   <div>
     <h3>Record List</h3>
     <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Position</th>
           <th>Level</th>
           <th>Action</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>{recordList()}</tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
 );
}
```

The record.js file in the server section.

```
const express = require("express");
 
// recordRoutes is an instance of the express router.
// We use it to define our routes.
// The router will be added as a middleware and will take control of requests starting with path /record.
const recordRoutes = express.Router();
 
// This will help us connect to the database
const dbo = require("../db/conn");
 
// This help convert the id from string to ObjectId for the _id.
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;
 
 
// This section will help you get a list of all the records.
recordRoutes.route("/record").get(function (req, res) {
 let db_connect = dbo.getDb("todolist");
 db_connect
   .collection("records")
   .find({})
   .toArray(function (err, result) {
     if (err) throw err;
     res.json(result);
   });
});
 
// This section will help you get a single record by id
recordRoutes.route("/record/:id").get(function (req, res) {
 let db_connect = dbo.getDb("todolist");
 let myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) };
 db_connect
   .collection("records")
   .findOne(myquery, function (err, result) {
     if (err) throw err;
     res.json(result);
   });
});
 
// This section will help you create a new record.
recordRoutes.route("/record/add").post(function (req, response) {
 let db_connect = dbo.getDb("todolist");
 let myobj = {
   name: req.body.name,
   position: req.body.position,
   level: req.body.level,
 };
 db_connect.collection("records").insertOne(myobj, function (err, res) {
   if (err) throw err;
   response.json(res);
 });
});
 
// This section will help you update a record by id.
recordRoutes.route("/update/:id").post(function (req, response) {
 let db_connect = dbo.getDb("todolist");
 let myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) };
 let newvalues = {
   $set: {
     name: req.body.name,
     position: req.body.position,
     level: req.body.level,
   },
 };
 db_connect
   .collection("records")
   .updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function (err, res) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log("1 document updated");
     response.json(res);
   });
});
 
// This section will help you delete a record
recordRoutes.route("/:id").delete((req, response) => {
 let db_connect = dbo.getDb("todolist");
 let myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) };
 db_connect.collection("records").deleteOne(myquery, function (err, obj) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log("1 document deleted");
   response.json(obj);
 });
});
 
module.exports = recordRoutes;
```

Comment: These aren't going to fix but here are some suggestions: 1. Move `setForm({ name: "", position: "", level: "" }); navigate("/");` into a `then` block before calling `catch`. 2. Listing `records.length` in the dependencies of `useEffect` would trigger unnecessary requests. Just imagine. Your `records.length` is 0. You fetch on mount. Then the length is X now. That change will trigger a new fetch again. 3. Are you positive that `response.ok` is present in the `response`? Getting `undefined` would make it pass through without getting back values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I put the fetch call in using a try and catch block like this. The database updates correctly and the button works as expected.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // When a post request is sent to the create url, we'll add a new record to the database.
    const newPerson = { ...form };
    try {
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/record/add", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(newPerson),
    });
    } catch (error){
      alert(error);
      return;
    }
    setForm({ name: "", position: "", level: "" });
    navigate("/");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check your api with a Postman API tester. Firstly check your back-end part. Is your created API working or not? If Your back-end API is working correctly then check the front-end part. It is helpful because you can understand which part of the problem.